# How to model system with different types of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roles, user-permissions

I am working on a restaurant franchise app. I've only ever had to use a User model and has secure password.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
```

Now I would have different types of users with different access rights and reports:

```
franchisor user (head office)
restaurant owner / franchisee
manager
waiter
```

What is a recommended way to set up the models/classes?
Would I create a model for each and give each `has_secure_password` or would I put everyone into the user model and assign them a type? Or do some sort of inheritance polymorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in one class and add a `role` column to User and assign a role to each User.

```
# in user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  ROLES = %w[ franchisor restaurant_owner manager waiter ]
  validates :role, :inclusion => { :in => ROLES }

  ROLES.each do |role_name|        # generates for each ROLE a method like this:
    def #{role_name}?              #     def waiter?
      role == '#{role_name}'       #       role == 'waiter'
    end                            #     end
  end
```

This allows you to ask something like `user.franchisor? || user.manager?` whenever you need different permissions.

This is simple and a good point to start. As long as it does not get more complex I would avoid using complex gems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain def #{role_name}?
      role == '#{role_name}' I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @spuggy that is metaprogramming. The block iterates over all `role_name`s in the `ROLES` array and creates a method for each `role_name` that checks if the current `role` has the given `role_name`. When you do not use metaprogramming here, you would need to implement all that methods by yourself. And need to add or remove methods when you change the `Roles` array. See updated answer, I added a example what is generated.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to manage your permissions and something like [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) or [Role Model](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) to define distinct roles for your different types of users.

I've written up a tutorial to get started with these here: http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/authentication-permissions-and-roles-in-rails-with-devise-cancan-and-role-model/