# Application with different types of users

Tags: java, user-interface, web, permissions

I'm building a quite extensive web application in Java from scratch for the first time, and need some guidance on the domain setup. The application is to be used both by teachers and students, and they will be able to do different things in the application, which also requires them to have different properties.

My idea is that the main entry into the domain is the User class. This class will hold things like name, email and login password. But, depending on if the person logging in is a teacher or a student, they must have access to different things. For example, a teacher must have a setting telling which subjects he or she is teaching in.

At first, this seemed like a typical inheritance problem to me: make the User class abstract and let the classes Teacher and Student extend User. But I'm not sure this is the best solution, so the main reason for me writing this is that I'm seeking a discussion that could get my mind out of the box that is this problem.

**Possible duplicates (and why I think they aren't):**

- [How to create pages with different permissions' views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184202/how-to-create-pages-with-different-permissions-views)
  This is about determining if a user has access to certain services, like viewing a page or clicking a button. It is a separate problem which can be solved by grouping User's into groups, giving each group a set of permissions, and checking those permissions. It isn't directly linked to my problem, even though it limits the options I have for solving My problem; there has to be a single point of entry for all logged in users (permissions are given to instances of a class User, and none else)
- [How to model system with different types of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268912/how-to-model-system-with-different-types-of-users)
  This also has to do with which actions each user have permission to perform, and not the actual properties of a user. Though, I've thought about using a structure like this; if a user has role TEACHER_ROLE then cast the user to a separate Teacher class. But I would rather solve this without having runtime dependent casting.

**TL;DR:**
What are the possible options when creating an application, where different logged in users should have different properties depending on what type of user they are?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the Canvas admin for the college I work at... quite often teachers will have student roles in a course space (workshop, departmental community group, etc), and occasionally students will have teacher roles (student clubs, etc using the course management system as a community communication tool).

So... I would have Folks.  And then define a bunch of true/false type permissions, both for course level and above.  And then I would create appropriate server level roles (admin, help desk, dept chair, etc) and course level roles (teacher, ta, student, etc) and decide which permissions they should have.

Someone logs in, they are on the server level and are either regular people, admins, or someone with partial admin rights.  If they have a course enrollment, then when they go into the course they have the rights that enrollment type is allowed to have in a course.

Take a look at the docs for Canvas, Desire2Learn, Moodle, Sakai, Blackboard, etc.  While all of them have different names for different things they all use the "people who have roles that have rights" model.

Comment: Funny thing you're writing @ivanivan, because the application I'm developing is actually an LMS quite similar to Canvas, yet a very scaled down version of it.

Comment: But how to I handle situations where the logged in User has different **properties**? For instance, a teacher would have a set of subjects they teach in. This is a property that a student would never have; this fail to see how this is solved by the "assign Roles to Users and Permissions to Roles"-solution (even though this is also necessary for other reasons).

Comment: User 1 is a "non-admin/non-helpdesk/non-Boss" user.  They log in to teh system, it identifies them as User 1, and it pulls a list of their enrollments.  The enrollment specifies a course space, and the role they have in that course space.  So I can log in to the server, and see that I'm enrolled in the Linux Admin class as a teacher, but also enrolled in the Java Servlets class as a student.  When I go into that particular course, I take on that role, with whatever rights it has.